# Breezejs with Awiat Async in Entity Framework?

Tags: asynchronous, breeze, entity-framework-6, async-await

I think Breezejs is a great tool but wonder if we can integrate EF and breeze further.
Specifically, can we use async methods and return `List<T>` instead of `IQueryable`?

For example:

```
public async Task<object> Lookups()
{
   var countries = await _repository.Countries.ToListAsync();
   var states = await _repository.States.ToListAsync();
   var parent = await _repository.Parent.Include(p => p.Children)
                                        .Include(p => p.Children.Address)
    return new { countries, states, locations, parent};
}
```

This works for simple objects like countries and states, but when the queries are more complicated, for example Parent-Child-Address, the Address disappears once in the client side.

It would be great to tap on all the async model while keeping all the Breeze features.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree.

We have it on our backlog to offer Web API helper components that support the async model. Please [add your vote to this User Voice topic](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5963097-breeze-web-api-components-should-support-async).